# Rounded border without border-radius

Tags: html, css, web, html4

I'm developing a website using with `HTML4`, `CSS2`. 
so I can't use border-radius property.
How can I create `<div>` or `<table>` what has rounded border?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `svg` with `object` tag & thats the only solution except using a round shaped image. Otherwise use `css3 polyfill` and use `border-radius`.

Comment: This should answer your question -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/6058075/8161432

Comment: You could give the `div` a `background-image` that has rounded corners.

Comment: What restricts you from using CSS3?

Comment: My customer demanded a factory monitoring system. They are using old version of web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found something related. Reference - [LINK](http://benogle.com/2009/04/29/css-round-corners.html)

```css
.b1,
.b2,
.b3,
.b4 {
  font-size: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.b1 {
  height: 1px;
  background: #888;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.b2 {
  height: 1px;
  border-right: 2px solid #888;
  border-left: 2px solid #888;
  margin: 0 3px;
}

.b3 {
  height: 1px;
  border-right: 1px solid #888;
  border-left: 1px solid #888;
  margin: 0 2px;
}

.b4 {
  height: 2px;
  border-right: 1px solid #888;
  border-left: 1px solid #888;
  margin: 0 1px;
}

.contentb {
  border-right: 1px solid #888;
  border-left: 1px solid #888;
}

.contentb div {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<b class="b1"></b><b class="b2"></b><b class="b3"></b><b class="b4"></b>
<div class="contentb">
  <div>Round Border!!</div>
</div>
<b class="b4"></b><b class="b3"></b><b class="b2"></b><b class="b1"></b>
```

Comment: It is really weird, but it works. I found that this works with HTML to PDF conversion with itext5.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of is some `svg` hacky method, for example:

```html
<svg width="500" height="400">
  <path d="M50,25 h300 a20,20 0 0 1 20,20 v200 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,20 h-300 a20,20 0 0 1 -20,-20 v-200 a20,20 0 0 1 20,-20 z" fill="none" stroke="#0089cc" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>
```

or you could create a transparent image in Photoshop/GIMP that has a border with rounded edges. Then, you could just use CSS `background-image` filepath URL to whatever `div` you'd like to target.

Answer (score 0):

```css
  #header {
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 93%;
            line-height: normal;
        }
        
        #header ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
        }
        
        #header li {
            float: left;
            background: url("https://image.ibb.co/kPAMhv/norm_right.gif") no-repeat right top;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        #header a {
            display: block;
            background: url("https://image.ibb.co/f01GFF/norm_left.gif") no-repeat left top;
            padding: 5px 15px;
        }
```

```html
  <div id="header">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

//realized that you're using css2

```
/*Your Id/class*/
div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 25px 50px 10px 23px;
}
```

Use border: to create the border first, then use border-radius to specify the radius.

You can enter multiple values to specify each edge. The patterns of the values are:
*top-left top-right bottom-left bottom-right*

You can also specify only one two or three values. Here is the pattern:

- **Four values:** first value applies to top-left, second value applies to top-right, third value applies to bottom-right, and fourth value applies to bottom-left corner
- **Three values:** first value applies to top-left, second value applies to top-right and bottom-left, and third value applies to bottom-right
- **Two values:** first value applies to top-left and bottom-right corner, and the second value applies to top-right and bottom-left corner
- **One value:** all four corners are rounded equally

Comment: He said he can't use CSS3 or border-radius.

Comment: How do I delete comments

Comment: If you want to delete a comment you made, there will be an 'x' on the right side of it.

Comment: I'm on mobile, There's no 'x' there

Comment: Do you mean delete your answer? That should be under your answer next to edit and flag.