# Creating a rounded image with limited standard CSS properties?

Tags: css, xhtml2pdf

Would it be possible to create a rounded image using a limited set of CSS properties? I am using python's [xhtml2pdf](https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and it only supports a few CSS properties.

The only CSS properties available are:

```
background-color
border-bottom-color, border-bottom-style, border-bottom-width
border-left-color, border-left-style, border-left-width
border-right-color, border-right-style, border-right-width
border-top-color, border-top-style, border-top-width
colordisplay
font-family, font-size, font-style, font-weight
height
line-height, list-style-type
margin-bottom, margin-left, margin-right, margin-top
padding-bottom, padding-left, padding-right, padding-top
page-break-after, page-break-before
size
text-align, text-decoration, text-indent
vertical-align
white-space
width
zoom
```

Comment: No, not really possible. You can create the image itself with any other library and insert the generated image in the pdf.

Comment: Thanks man. I'll just use PIL to make the image round. You can post this as the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Didn't test with an `img` but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877101/rounded-border-without-border-radius) is about having rounded borders without border-radius, might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly this is not possible with this limited set of CSS properties.

But you can use another library to modify an existing image and create a version of the image with a round border (and add some filters to it, do whatever you want basically)

Edit: Since PIL was mentioned in a comment: [PIL round edges and add border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38539277/pil-round-edges-and-add-border) (something like this, see also linked questions/answers)

Then you just use this image in the pdf, no one will notice any difference.